# UIPIckerView in UIActionSheet in a TabBarController

Tags: ios5, uipickerview, uitabbar, uiactionsheet

I am trying to create a UIPickerView inside of a UIActionSheet with a "done" button in a bar on the action sheet above the picker and I am trying to display the action sheet from the tab bar.

here is the code I am using to create my picker:

```
    _beepPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
    _beepPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    _beepPicker.dataSource = self;
    _beepPicker.delegate = self;
```

here is the code I am using to create my action sheet (with my "done" button)

```
_beepPickerActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:nil 
                              delegate:nil 
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    UISegmentedControl *doneButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
    doneButton.momentary = YES; 
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    doneButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissBeepPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [_beepPickerActionSheet addSubview:doneButton];
```

and here is how I'm adding my "done" button:

```
[_beepPickerActionSheet addSubview:_beepPicker];
```

and finally, here is how I am trying to display the action sheet:

```
[_beepPickerActionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

The Action Sheet does display... but, I can only see about 30 pixels of the top of the Action sheet????????

Any idea what I may be doing incorrectly?

When I check my debugger... here is what I see for the frame of the Action Sheet

UIActionSheet: 0x6b304f0; frame = (0 455; 320 25);

Screenshot before:

[image]

Screenshot after:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I know what I was doing incorrect... I had to add

```
[_beepPickerActionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320,485)];
```

After I added it to the view.